# sql subtract dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Some of the dates in a column of dates were recorded wrong. I'd like to make a query which subtracts one day from each date IF the days are in a certain date range.

I know I'll have to use DATEADD and UPDATE, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
UPDATE  [SomeTable]
SET     [DateColumn] = DATEADD(d, -1, [DateColumn])
WHERE   [DateColumn] BETWEEN [Date1] AND [Date2]
```

Here's the MSDN doc's on the `DATEADD` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

When performing updates on data like this, it's always best to run a select statement **first** with the same criteria to ensure that you're updating the correct records. It also helps reduce the stress level of updating (especially if you're unfamiliar with SQL).

```
SELECT    *, --Depending on what columns you would like to see, the wildcard could be replaced
          DATEADD(d, -1, [DateColumn]) AS ProposedDate
FROM      [SomeTable]
WHERE     [DateColumn] BETWEEN [Date1] AND [Date2]
```

Comment: On the test query, it would be better if you use `DATEADD(d, -1, [DateColumn])` instead of `*`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @min_date datetime, @max_date datetime;

UPDATE yourtable
SET date_column = DATEADD(day, -1, date_column)
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM yourtable
  WHERE date_column BETWEEN @min_date AND @max_date
);
```

You'll have to set appropriate values for `@min_date` and `@max_date`.

Comment: @JNK: I've found the pattern easier to follow as the criteria for updating gets more complex. Probably not needed in this case, but it keeps the `UPDATE` part of the statement simple.

Comment: OK, just curious if you saw something I didn't :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET DateField = DATEADD(Day, -1, DateField)
WHERE Datefield BETWEEN '1/1/2011' AND '2/1/2011'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use UPDATE
set the data = ( do the date math )
WHERE the date is in the range you want
and the key is the row you want.
```

Comment: this is the same language the OP is using to ask the question.  I am giving pseudocode response to a pseudo-question.